# Do I always see all the tweets of people I'm following on Twitter?

Tags: twitter

Just a idle curiosity here, but I've wondered if at certain times I'm not seeing all the tweets by the people I follow.

A couple of things have led me to this conclusion:

1. At the moment I'm on pretty much all day (some days) and I would have thought that with the "N new tweets" messages and the occasional reload I'd see everything, but sometimes I see a tweet which is clearly a reply to something someone else posted earlier when I don't remember seeing it.
2. There are some people I hardly see any tweets from at all, yet when I check their profiles they have recent activity.

I'll freely admit that I can't remember all the tweets I see during a day, but I'm not following that many active people so I'm fairly likely to remember if X or Y posted.

I should add that I use the web interface (rather than a desktop app or any other feed) to view Twitter and I'm using Google Chrome on Windows-XP (just in case it makes a difference).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say yes you do receive them all.

<strike>Certain replies unless you follow both users are not able to be seen.</strike>

Cases for replies and mentions :

1. Your account is protected mentions
   sent to people who aren't following
   you will not be seen.
2. You will only see replies in your
   home time line if you are following
   both the sender and recipient of the
   tweet
3. You will see mentions not replies in
   your timeline as long as you are
   following the sender

Even during the heaviest traffic times in World Cup I was able to see all the user tweets.
The home timeline only receives 20 tweets without the refresh using the more button or the "N new tweets" message. That way it might seem to someone that they are not receiving all the tweets.

For example if X users > 20 posted at 2:30 pm during a World Cup game , it would appear to you that person Y's tweet is missing. It is there , it is just that the timeline only displays 20.

To verify this , you can test with the following tabs open on your browser.

- http://twitter.com/home
- http://snapbird.org/ (Search your
  friends' tweets and blank for the
  search term)
- http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/home_timeline.xml
  (Inspect in web developer mode using
  your firefox or chrome browser)

Looking at these three will tell you that you are in fact getting all your tweets.

**Edit**

If you inspect a user's timeline and are sure that it does not match up with the three above then I would suggest to check http://status.twitter.com/ to see the current status of any errors that are occurring site-wide.

If you think it is more localized you can submit a *Twicket* : http://help.twitter.com/requests/new

Think your *Twicket* is taking too long shoot a mention to [@delbius](http://twitter.com/delbius) the lead on Twitter's Trust and Safety team.

Comment: I should have added that I know I don't see @ replies to people I'm not following myself.

Comment: Okay I updated for error status updates there was actually some missing replies earlier this month http://status.twitter.com/post/773257081/missing-replies

Comment: "Certain replies unless you follow both users are not able to be seen."
   
What determines when this will occur?

Comment: Replies and Mentions are mixed alot : Cases : **1** Your account is protected mentions sent to people who aren't following you will not be seen. **2** You will only see replies in your home time line if you are following both the sender and recipient of the tweet **3** You will see mentions not replies in your timeline as long as you are following the sender

Answer (score 1):

I was going crazy as well not seeing tweets from many people I follow, and that's how I landed here but was just able to figure out where Twitter I believe is trying to hide it! There is an icon on TOP RIGHT, something that looks like a 4-point star. Clicking on that gives the option  "Switch to Latest Tweets" which it says will show tweets "as they happen". Hope it does!

Answer (score -1):

Actually the answer is no. If you are following someone who is an activist or politician and their tweets can be classified as offensive to some religion or race etc then twitter shadow bans them. This means their tweets will not appear on your time line and you have to go their profile to see their tweets. I follow someone who is a teenage girl and an activist against radical groups and terrorism and she tweets almost 100 tweets a day. Even prime minister of my country follows her but she has been shadow banned from my time line and others.if I have to see her tweets then I have to go and see her profile page. Such algorithms are made where some people will be flagged and categorized and tagged as a group of people with similar views. If they reach a certain number followers then twitter starts shadow banning them.

Comment: Cite your sources, please.

Comment: Also I see some (or most) tweets in my timeline so I know that they're not "shadow banned".

Comment: Actually, there is something to this. There are some accounts that Twitter does in fact appear to shadow ban. Here are a few non-extreme examples: `@wikileaks`, `@BenSwann_`, `@mercola`, `@jordanbpeterson`. Still following these accounts, and regularly read their content but I NEVER receive their tweets in my twitter feed for the last year or more. Other followers have complained about similar issues with not receiving tweets from these accounts and other controversial-to-mainstream media sources. Try following some of these accounts temporariiy and see for yourself.

Comment: At this point, it's beyond naïve to think Twitter isn't censoring things it doesn't like. Here's a source: https://thefederalist.com/2018/01/11/twitter-employees-brag-about-shadow-banning-users-video/